# Creating bar chart from point layer using QGIS Geometry Generator

Tags: qgis, point, chart, geometry-generator, geometry-conversion

From a layer with point geometry, I store the following fields:

- `"CATEG"` which can be A or B
- `"ORDER"` which is an autonumeric field sequence without repetitions
- `"VALUE"` which is a value

Points are distributed/digitalized in the space according to where the phenomenon occurs. The attribute table design is shown in the following screenshot:

[image]

My goal is to transform/translate this point cloud layer into a pseudo-bar chart. The points should be translated in a straight line that would be the X axis with the values from the minimum value of the `"ORDER"` field (1) to the maximum value of the `"ORDER"` field (12).

Then I would like to draw an arrow representing the value of the `"VALUE"` field.

Here is a screenshot made manually with the idea I'm looking for:

[image]

The solution presented by user [Babel](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/88814/babel) is exactly what I was looking for. I am speechless!

To refine the solution a little more. I am trying to color the arrows with the field "CATEG" which is a string, and I use the following expression, but I can't get it to work:

```
CASE
  WHEN "CATEG" = 'A' THEN '#b2f0cf'
  WHEN "CATEG" = 'B' THEN '#46b2fa'
  ELSE '#000000'
END
```

[image]

I have also tried to create a numeric field (with values 1 and 2) and use the Categoritzed symbol renderer and I have not been able to color either:

[image]

I can't manage the arrow colors using "CATEG" field. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I add an animated screenshot showing my workflow. Could you help me to find out what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Will a standard QGIS's [Bar plot](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/plots.html#bar-plot) tool satisfy your demand? It has both category and value fields.

Comment: I have tried the Bar plot algorithm from the Processing toolbox, and also the Data Plotly plugin. Both options allow to achieve the objective. But in my project they have the problem that you have to pre-generate the calculation and also generates an HTML file that is not very suitable to integrate in my print layout. My main requirement is that the transformation can be done on-the-fly with the geometry generator and that the translation in straight line is done in the same space where there are the points

Comment: Just interesting, when you project your all points on the X-axis, how should they be placed, with a standard increment e.g. 50m, or appropriated to old projected locations, but swapped according to the `"ORDER"` field ?

Comment: Is a combination of `QGIS` and `Excel` using `PowerQuery` an option?

Comment: Have you tried using symbology and the geometry generator/`make_point()`?

Comment: Taras, the idea would be, for example, to have an X-axis of fixed length and that the values (1 to 12, in this case) are distributed equidistantly.
The option you propose (fixed increment of 50m) would also be good.

Comment: Bernd, Yes, it is a good idea this combination, but as in the case of Data Plotly and Bar chart, my requirement is that the transformation can be done on-the-fly, so that it can be easily integrated in my print layout

Comment: Erik, not yet. I'm still stuck on what approach would be the most appropriate to take

Comment: If anyone interested - I have updated my answer with a solution using Chart.JS in an HTML frame within the print composer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the following expression in [Geoemtry Generator](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html#the-geometry-generator), style the resulting [line as arrow](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html#line-symbols) and assign the color corresponding to the category values (see below for that). The expression creates a bar chart, ordered based on the field `order`, with the length of the field `value` and using the extent of the point layer.

This works for whatever CRS and layer extent you use - it will automatically adapt: if you add/delete or move points or if you change attribute values, the bars will change accordingly.

*Initial points (yellow) and bar chart, created inside the extent of the point layer (black dotted line) and based on the `order` and `value` attributes of the points; bars/arrow heads are again labeled in the corresponding color from attribute `categ`:*

[image]

```
with_variable(
    'ext',
    layer_property( @layer, 'extent'),
with_variable(
    'ln',
    translate (
        make_point (x_min(@ext),y_min(@ext)),
        (order-0.5) * (x_max(@ext)-x_min(@ext)) / count ($id),
        0
    ),
make_line (
    @ln,
    project(
        @ln,
        attribute (get_feature(@layer, 'order', "order"),'value') * (y_max(@ext)-y_min(@ext)) / maximum(value),
        0
    )
)))
```

---

##### Details for styling

To **color the bars** depending on their `categ` values, use this expression:

```
case
when categ = 'A' then 'red'
else 'blue'
end
```

The **extent of the point layer** (black dotted line on my screenshot) is easy to create with Geometry Generator: `layer_property (@layer, 'extent')`

To **place the label at the top of the bar** (arrow head), in the label placement tab, activate `Geoemtry Generator` and paste the following expression (based on the one above to create the bars): it gets the *end-point of the bar-lines*. Then set placement mode to `Offset from Point` and the Quadrant to the center top:

[image]

```
with_variable(
    'ext',
    layer_property( @layer, 'extent'),
with_variable(
    'ln',
    translate (
            make_point (x_min(@ext),y_min(@ext)),
            (order-0.5) * (x_max(@ext)-x_min(@ext)) / count ($id),
            0
        ),
end_point (
    make_line (
        @ln,
        project(
            @ln,
            value * (y_max(@ext)-y_min(@ext)) /maximum(value),
            0
        )
    )
)))
```

Comment: I can't manage the symbology arrows by colors according to the "CATEG" field. I add an animated screenshot showing my workflow. Could you help me on the steps to follow to categorize the arrows by color?

Comment: I realize it works your expression for solution color categories. However, in my project I cannot use it. It is unviable because I have more than 100 features

Comment: Sorry, my expression was a bit too complex for the task... I found an easier version that has the big advantage that it is very easy to color the bars as you want. See updated answer. Sorry for the initial confusion!

Comment: Thank you. Now, this expression works. If possible, I would like to ask for two more things, if you could share:

- The expression to draw the extent of the point layer (black dotted line)
- The expression to control the placement of the label above the arrow

Comment: I added this at the end of my solution and I revised the initial expression to generate the bars once again to make it shorter.

Answer (score 10):

Let's assume there is an input point layer called *'points_in_polygon'* with its attribute table, see the image below.

[image: input]

Attributes Imitatation :

- `"city"` → `"CATEG"`
- `"month"` → `"ORDER"`
- `"temp"` → `"VALUE"`

### Solution 1 : Single Symbol

[image: solution1]

#### Stage 1 : Geometry Generator

Geometry Type : Point/MultiPoint

Expression Dialog:

```
geometry_n(
    order_parts(
        nodes_to_points(
            densify_by_count(
                make_line(
                    make_point(
                            x_min(layer_property(@layer, 'extent')),
                            y_min(layer_property(@layer, 'extent'))
                            ),
                    make_point(
                            x_max(layer_property(@layer, 'extent')),
                            y_min(layer_property(@layer, 'extent'))
                            )
                    ),
                (layer_property(@layer, 'feature_count') - 2)
                )
            ),
        orderby:="month"
        ),
    array_find(array_agg($id, order_by:="month"), $id) + 1
    )
```

#### Stage 2 : Filled Marker

Type : Arrow marker
Size : Expression String Builder

```
scale_linear("temp", 0, 10, minimum("temp"), maximum("temp"))
```

#### Stage 3 : Simple fill

Color : Expression String Builder

```
case
    when attribute('city') = 'PARIS' then '#fb5607'
    when attribute('city') = 'LONDON' then '#8338ec'
    else '#344e41'
end
```

And get the following result:

[image: result1]

---

### Solution 2 : Single Symbol

[image: solution2]

#### Stage 1 : Geometry Generator

Geometry Type : LineString/MultiLineString

Expression Dialog:

```
make_line(
    geometry_n(
            order_parts(
                nodes_to_points(
                    densify_by_count(
                        make_line(
                            make_point(
                                    x_min(layer_property(@layer, 'extent')),
                                    y_min(layer_property(@layer, 'extent'))
                                    ),
                            make_point(
                                    x_max(layer_property(@layer, 'extent')),
                                    y_min(layer_property(@layer, 'extent'))
                                    )
                            )
                        ,
                        (layer_property(@layer, 'feature_count') - 2)
                        )
                    ),
                orderby:="month"
                ),
            array_find(array_agg($id, order_by:="month"), $id) + 1),
    project(
        geometry_n(
            order_parts(
                nodes_to_points(
                    densify_by_count(
                        make_line(
                            make_point(
                                    x_min(layer_property(@layer, 'extent')),
                                    y_min(layer_property(@layer, 'extent'))
                                    ),
                            make_point(
                                    x_max(layer_property(@layer, 'extent')),
                                    y_min(layer_property(@layer, 'extent'))
                                    )
                            )
                        ,
                        (layer_property(@layer, 'feature_count') - 2)
                        )
                    ),
                orderby:="month"
                ),
            array_find(array_agg($id, order_by:="month"), $id) + 1),
        "temp",
        0
        )
    )
```

#### Stage 2 : Simple Line

Color : Expression String Builder

```
case
    when attribute('city') = 'PARIS' then '#fb5607'
    when attribute('city') = 'LONDON' then '#8338ec'
    else '#344e41'
end
```

And get the following result:

[image: result2]

*P.S.* LineString object can be converted into [Arrow](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html#line-symbols).

---

Both solutions possess the same label configurations:

Value :

```
'id: ' || "id" || 
'\n' ||
'city: ' ||"city" || 
'\n' ||
'month: ' || "month" || 
'\n' ||
'temp: ' || "temp"
```

Mode : Offset from Point
Quadrant : Below
Offset Y : 3,00 mm
Placement : Geometry Generator

```
geometry_n(
    order_parts(
        nodes_to_points(
            densify_by_count(
                make_line(
                    make_point(
                            x_min(layer_property(@layer, 'extent')),
                            y_min(layer_property(@layer, 'extent'))
                            ),
                    make_point(
                            x_max(layer_property(@layer, 'extent')),
                            y_min(layer_property(@layer, 'extent'))
                            )
                    )
                ,
                (layer_property(@layer, 'feature_count') - 2)
                )
            ),
        orderby:="month"
        ),
    array_find(array_agg($id, order_by:="month"), $id) + 1)
```

Geometry Type : Point/MultiPoint

[image: labelling]

---

**References:**

- [colours | Trending Color Palettes](https://coolors.co/palettes/trending)
- [Assign multiple colors to features within a single vector layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20404/assign-multiple-colors-to-features-within-a-single-vector-layer)

Comment: +1. However, I'm not sure if the size of the arrow marker reliably reflects proportionally attribute vales in the style of a bar chart. Temp= 9 and Temp=29 look almost the same size. As well, height **and** width are scaled based on the attribute value and this is difficult to interpret.

Comment: You are right! One can always adjust that thing, it is simply a matter of time to find that balance :)

Comment: The SVG symbology can be also used, it is pretty useful because it has width and height at the same time, not only the size

Comment: Both Taras' first and second solutions work perfectly. Could you share the Label Placement expression for Solution 2 please?

Answer (score 4):

### **Solution using Excel**

Using `PowerQuery` within `Excel` (only works for Office on Windows) you can access your local data (GeoJSON for example) or even remote data (PostGres DB etc.). So after setting your workflow up you just need to press refresh.

1. Store your data as GeoJSON
2. Load your data within Excel using PowerQuery (Data --> Get Data --> From File --> JSON). Now the `GeoJSON` is loaded but needs to be extracted.

[image]

3. Extract features --> Click on `List` next to `features`

[image]

4. Now we need to convert the list into a column of records by clicking `Convert to Table`

[image]

5. We only want the `properties` so we uncheck the `geometry` and `type` column.

[image]

6. By clicking the two arrays in the column header the `properties` get exploded.
   [image]
7. Finally we change the data-types of the `ORDER` and `VALUE` column to decimal.

[image]

8. Now the data can be loaded into an Excel Table.
9. Create a pivot `stacked bar-chart` from your data where the `ORDER` column is set as the `row`, the `CATEG` column is set as `column` and `VALUE` is set as `values`.

[image]

10. Store your chart as a png after each update.

Now you only need to click refresh in Excel and update the png. The png can be imported as an image to your print report.

Here is a sample PowerQuery ([M formula language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/)) Code. You can import it as an empty query. Just replace the GeoJSON Path

```
let
    Quelle = Json.Document(File.Contents(<GeoJSON Path>)),
    features = Quelle[features],
    #"In Tabelle konvertiert" = Table.FromList(features, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Erweiterte Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"In Tabelle konvertiert", "Column1", {"properties"}, {"properties"}),
    #"Erweiterte properties" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Erweiterte Column1", "properties", {"CATEG", "ORDER", "VALUE"}, {"CATEG", "ORDER", "VALUE"}),
    #"Geänderter Typ" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Erweiterte properties",{{"ORDER", type number}, {"VALUE", type number}})
in
    #"Geänderter Typ"
```

[image: Wofklow]

### **Solution using Chart.JS within Print Layout**

Another option would be to use `Chart.JS` library within an HTML frame in the printer composer. Using the `aggregate expression` like `[[%aggregate( layer:='data',aggregate:='concatenate',expression:=if(CATEG='A', VALUE||'', '0'), concatenator:=',')%]]` you can directly create the needed JavaScript config for a `Chart.JS` stacked bar chart.

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha512-vBmx0N/uQOXznm/Nbkp7h0P1RfLSj0HQrFSzV8m7rOGyj30fYAOKHYvCNez+yM8IrfnW0TCodDEjRqf6fodf/Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.css" integrity="sha512-SUJFImtiT87gVCOXl3aGC00zfDl6ggYAw5+oheJvRJ8KBXZrr/TMISSdVJ5bBarbQDRC2pR5Kto3xTR0kpZInA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
   </head>
   <body>
      <div>
         <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
      </div>
      <script>
         const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
         
         new Chart(ctx, {
           type: 'bar',
         data: {
         labels: [[%aggregate( layer:='data',aggregate:='concatenate',expression:=ORDER||'', concatenator:=',')%]],
         datasets: [
            {
                label: "Category A",
                data: [[%aggregate( layer:='data',aggregate:='concatenate',expression:=if(CATEG='A', VALUE||'', '0'), concatenator:=',')%]],
                borderWidth: 1,
                backgroundColor: '#67c1e9'
            },
            {
                label: "Category B",
                data: [[%aggregate( layer:='data',aggregate:='concatenate',expression:=if(CATEG='B', VALUE||'', '0'), concatenator:=',')%]],
                borderWidth: 1,
                backgroundColor: '#ca6fb3'
            }
         ]
         },
         options: {
         animation: {
            duration: 0
         },
         scales: {
                   yAxes: [
                {
                    stacked: true,
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }
            ],
            xAxes: [
                {
                    stacked: true,              
                }
            ]
         }
         }
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

[image]